# iOS DropDown CocoaPod

Tags: drop-down-menu, cocoapods

I am trying to get to grips with iOS DropDown cocoapod

```
import UIKit
import iOSDropDown

class CountryConfirmViewController: UIViewController {

    //var buttonTapped = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var countryLabel: DropDown!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dropDown()
    }
            
    @IBAction func confirmCountry(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToUser", sender: self)
    }
           
    func dropDown() {
        countryLabel.optionArray = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
        countryLabel.showList()
    }
}
```

The code above produces a dropdown menu but I can't get the data chosen by the user and move it to another controller. I can't find anything on the CocoaPod website about it or anywhere else.

Comment: can you at least share the library's link

Comment: https://cocoapods.org/pods/iOSDropDown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow related library's documentation properly, I've found this code block;

```swift
dropDown.didSelect{(selectedText , index ,id) in
self.valueLabel.text = "Selected String: \(selectedText) \n index: \(index)"
}
```

You can grab selection, from the method `didSelect`

Comment: What is index and id?

Comment: you do not need to use those, if you don't interest. index should be the order of the selected Item in your dataSource array

Comment: `didSelect ` returns informations you about the selectedItem. 3 parameter: `selectedText`, `index`, `id`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand, there are 3 parameters but i don't need to use them?

Comment: I got it to work, i did need to use two parameters string and index, id wasn't needed

Comment: I'm not sure, copy and pasting from that website then telling me that I did not need to use those parameters when I did need to use them wasn't that helpful, but thanks for trying and i will mark it accepted because at least you tried to help, cheers